# Showing images in HTML email

Tags: html, css, image, email, html-email

I'm sending an HTML email with linked images, like:
`<img src="https://www.test.com/image.jpg">`

When I open them on my iPhone Mail app it doesn't show the images, even though I have Mail set to auto-load images. Every other email I open auto-loads images. When I open them on my Mac Mail client they do load. Is there anything special I have to do in my HTML to get the images to load? I looked at my source compared to emails that I can see the images and they appear to be doing the same thing. Any ideas? 
Thanks

Comment: Please always share your code what you have done till now. It will be helpful to undersatnd .

Comment: It's probably better practice to use data URLs in emails than to load external images, since most email clients default to blocking them.

Comment: @Cobra_Fast Not so. Always use external images; most in fact load them by default. Data URLs are not well supported, so will completely fail, but pressing a button to download images is normal.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out this occurs if you use "HTTPS" for image links. Once I changed them to HTTP the images loaded fine. Thanks

Comment: I don't think that is the issue, unless your images were served from a `http` and you coded the url to be `https`. There is a whole discussion on stack overflow about using `https` only as it might become a norm.